# Penalty notice for speed limit violation in Australia while I am an Indian citizen

Tags: legal, driving, australia

We hired rented cars in Australia during our visit as tourists there. After 3 months of coming back we received a penalty reminder notices of same day, same highway for exceeding the speeding limit. My speed was 66Km ( while limit was 60kmph). Two notices are within a duration of 1 hour.
The total amount is 226 AuD each. I am in India now & as such don't have any plans to visit Australia in near future, but I do visit other countries.

I need to know how it will impact me if I don't pay the fine and is there a possibility to get a waiver of this fine?

Comment: General information: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/do-i-have-to-pay-traffic-fines-issued-by-foreign-governments/3334#3334

Comment: What were the car rental terms and conditions regarding speeding fines?

Comment: Why not just pay it? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89631/do-traffic-offences-have-to-be-included-on-the-uk-visitor-visa-application?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Traveller that's about INR 22,000.  It seems to be around the same order of magnitude as one month's earnings for an IT worker in India.

Comment: @phoog I appreciate that, however the OP had the wherewithal to make the trip, therefore may be able to pay but just doesn’t want to unless there’s likely to be any consequences.  I just feel there’s a moral side to this question - is it ok to break the law without paying the penalty just because you’re a visitor and can get away with it.

Comment: @Traveller I absolutely agree that there's a moral side to it.  I just wanted to put the amount into context.