Will I have to disclose traffic tickets to immigration (general)
Since some countries ask you to disclose convictions, would speeding tickets (United States) be included? I ask this because most people have received multiple speeding tickets throughout their life, and probably don't remember them all. Making this worse is that many countries require authorization to travel there (not to be confused with a full visa), usually applied for online. Some of these ask for criminal history or past convictions, but do not give you a chance to explain exactly what the offense was, and automatically deny you. However, the laws for these countries usually (if not always) do not consider a speeding ticket grounds to deny entry. This leads to a situation where you have three options: One, saying "yes" and definitely get denied (if it is all digital) Two, saying "no" and risk getting denied for "lying", especially in countries that the US shares records with, even if it isn't technically a lie, just a misunderstanding. Or three, spend extra money and time getting a full visa with interviews, etc.
How would I go about answering conviction/criminal records questions on ETA or arrival cards if I don't remember when and where all of my speeding/traffic tickets were?

Speeding tickets are usually not a criminal conviction.

I don't think there is a worldwide answer to this question. When asked a question on an immigration form, you should read it and answer what it asks, not what similar questions in other countries ask.

@littleadv: not about US, but on some countries it may be a crime (depending on speed and where and if repeated). In any case a crime must have a decision from a judge (but judges decides also non-crimes), so it is seldom a crime.

Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89631/do-traffic-offences-have-to-be-included-on-the-uk-visitor-visa-application

“most people have received multiple speeding tickets throughout their life” [citation needed] — I doubt that’s true, even limiting “most” to “people with a driving license”.

@Stephen_Kitt it took me thirty years of driving, but they got me eventually :-(

On an immigration form read the notes and how-to-compete documentation carefully and do exactly what you are told to. Chances are there is an instruction to omit traffic offences punished by a fine, but if not, play safe and declare them.

if I don't remember when and where all of my speeding/traffic tickets were - it's one thing if you know it was a minor offence, but if you can't remember what you were charged with, then you should probably find out by requesting your record from the appropriate authorities, and speak to an immigration lawyer if you're still unsure.

Perhaps the OP is unaware of the distinction between felonies and misdemeanors in the US. Legal references call both of these "crimes" but based on earlier comments I guess the authorities really want to know about felonies.

@GiacomoCatenazzi It's state dependent in the US. In Texas and Oklahoma, for example, all speeding is a criminal misdemeanor.

Generally no: speeding tickets do not need to be mentioned. Each country and form has its specific wording which you should carefully read before answering truthfully. The vast majority (but perhaps not all) will not bother with speeding tickets.
For example the US ESTA version reads

Have you ever been arrested or convicted for a crime that resulted in serious damage to property, or serious harm to another person or government authority?


Have you ever violated any law related to possessing, using, or distributing illegal drugs?

Another good one is:

Do you seek to engage in or have you ever engaged in terrorist activities, espionage, sabotage, or genocide?


Interesting about the wording "Have you ever been arrested or convicted..."  Quite often people get arrested and then released without further action, either because the wrong person was arrested or because upon investigation there was no criminal offence committed, or whatever other reasons.  Now, just the fact that you were (possibly mistakenly) arrested means you can't get ESTA.

Also interestng is "Have you ever violated any law related to...", rather than "...been arrested/charged/convicted of violating any law...". It seems to demand self-incrimination of anyone who's ever possed drugs, even if they never came to the notice of the authorities.

@AleksG "Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good." Entry is a privilege, not a right, we don't need to implement due process when deciding who to allow into the country. While false arrests happen, probably the vast majority of arrests are reasonable. It may be annoying to be refused entry because of this, we consider it more acceptable than allowing entry to criminals who got off on a technicality.

@Barmar I'm not complaining, just stating a fact.  Plus, I myself am a US citizen, so don't need any special permission to enter.

@AleksG: Bear in mind, just because you answer "yes" doesn't necessarily mean the ESTA will be denied. The government does say that you can be denied if you're inadmissible under 212(a), and that can arise from criminal activity via subparagraph (2), but looking more closely at the law, it looks like a wrongful arrest would not qualify in most situations. Also, you always have the option of applying for a B visa instead of an ESTA, at which point there are stronger procedural protections.

"Are you now, or have you ever been, a member of the Communist Party?"

@Barmar: The vast majority of arrests in the US are not reasonable.
